# Select rows based on same conditions across multiple Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with Python 3.7, and I am trying to select rows from multiple Pandas DataFrame based on the same condition.

In particular, suppose that I have a DataFrame, df, with two columns = ['Name', 'Gender'], and the 'Gender' column can take only three values 'M', 'F', 'U'.

My objective is to select the rows that have gender equal to 'M' or 'F'.
However, I will have to make this selection for multiple dataframes with the same columns,  therefore I was trying to store the condition in an object, using the lambda function, as follows:

```
_M = (lambda x: x['Gender']=='M')
_F = (lambda x: x['Gender']=='F')
new_df = df.loc[_M | _F]
```

However, it throws the following exception:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'function' and 'function'"
```

Therefore I tried to substitute '|' for 'or':

```
new_df = df.loc[_M or _F]
```

and in this case I don't get any errors, but it only selects rows based on the _M condition.

(Note that I would like to keep both _M and _F as separate conditions as I need to work separately on rows with Gender=='M' and Gender='F' at a later stage.)

EDIT:
My question is therefore how to select rows from different pandas dataframes, using the same condition, in an efficient way.
More generally, I would like to know what is the correct way to combine conditions using the lambda function, if any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
df[(df['Gender'] == 'M') | (df['Gender'] == 'F')]
```

You need to remember to put brackets around you conditions when using `|`.
Alternatively, if the values are guaranteed to be either `'M', 'F', 'U'`, then you could try.

```
df[~df['Gender'] == 'U'] # This selects anything that isn't 'U'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning both the variable separately ie.
new_df = df.loc[_M ]
new_df = df.loc[_F] 
Hope this helps.......

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer to my question, but for my purposes it works.

I just edited my code and added another condition as follows:

```
_M = (lambda x: x['Gender']=='M')
_F = (lambda x: x['Gender']=='F')
_MF = lambda x: (x['Gender']=='M') | (x['Gender']=='F')
new_df = df.loc[_MF]
```

and in this way I have what I need.

Still, I would like to know if there is a way to generalize the combination of conditions to select rows from multiple dataframes.